# converting integer to string through ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

i have the following ajax code to update the password in my database table,

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: root_url + '/services/services.php?method=updatesubpwd',
    data: { 
        'sid': ptcid, 
        'pwd': prtpwd // <-- the $ sign in the parameter name seems unusual, I would avoid it
    },
    //data: "sid=" + ptcid + "&pwd=" + prtpwd,
    async: true,

    success: function (data) {
        alert(prtpwd);
        if ($('.dynapwdblock') && $('.dynapwdblock').css('display')=="none") {
            $('#prepwd').val(prtpwd);
            $('.prtpwd').val(prtpwd);
            $('#prtpwdval').val(prtpwd);

            $('.apfnp').remove();
            $('.dynapwdblock').show(200);
            //alert(data);
        }

    },
    ...
```

everything seems working fine when i give the values for my `prtpwd` field in data of ajax, But in case of numbers when i give the numbers starting with "0" or starting with series of "0"s the first 0's are not storing in the database that means it is storing as Integer, can anyone tell me how should i change the function so as to accept the starting 0's to store in DB

```
 prtpwd=$('#prtpwd').val();
```

this is from where the ajax is getting the prtpwd value from.

and this is the function used to set the data into the DB

```
function updateSubPassword($subid, $pwd)
    {
        $query       = "UPDATE Sub SET Sign_pw=".$pwd." WHERE Sub_id=" . $subid;
        $queryresult = mysql_query($query);

        if ($queryresult) {
            return 1;
        } else
            return 0;
    }
```

the leading zero's are not saving in the DB though the data type is Varchar

Comment: what's the datatype of the field where you are storing the 0's?

Comment: The value seems to be converted into an integer. Maybe `prtpwd` is an integer, or maybe it's the database's corresponding field, or maybe some mess happens in your PHP script. Can you check and report the code?

Comment: my datatype in db is varchar only

Answer (score 0):

If you have the column in you database set to 'integer' the zeros will get when you try and save to the db.  change the column type to varchar or text or something similar (depending on what db you are using).  Also make sure you are passing a string to the ajax call and not an integer.  An easy way of doing that .....

```
var myString = ""
myString = myString + variableIThinkMightBeAnInteger
```

Comment: That won't do if `variableIThinkMightBeAnInteger` is actually an integer, i.e. it won't put the leading zeros back.

Comment: @MaxArt i updated the prtpwd field can u check that in the code

Answer (score 0):

You can change the column in your database to fill it with zeros. just set the type to `INT` with the `Length` of max digits and attribute to `UNSIGNED ZEROFILL`.

Example:

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename`
CHANGE `pwdfield` `pwdfield` INT( 8 ) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL
```

This makes your password field a max of 8 digits and if only 4 are given, it is padded with zeros, i.e. if you get a number `1234` to put in the database, the cell will fill it to `00001234`. That's what the `UNSIGNED ZEROFILL` is for

Comment: no...i should not change the DB type it should allow everything so i should keep varchar itself

Answer (score 0):

When doing the query for updating the password, put single quotation marks around `$pwd`:

```
$query       = "UPDATE Sub SET Sign_pw='$pwd' WHERE Sub_id=$subid";
```

This should force the value to be a string. It may be worth to do the same with `$subid` too.

(Also, why don't you get advantage of the PHP double quotation mark notation?)